# Why is the expression register "read only"?

Tags: history-of, expression-register

I was messing with the expression register ([`:h @=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#@=)) and noticed that it is not possible to put text directly in it. The doc says:

> The expression register is read-only; you cannot put text into it.

Let's say my buffer contains an operation like that:

```
1+2+3+4
```

If I want to get the result in the expression register, I have to do the following:

- <kbd>yf4</kbd>: Put the expression into the unnamed register
- <kbd>"=</kbd>: Start editing the expression register
- <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>: Put the content of the unnamed register into the expression register

If the expression register weren't read only I could have done it more easily:

- <kbd>"=yf4</kbd> Select the expression register and put the line into it.

So my question is not about how I could change this behavior but **what can explain this implementation?**

Is it because yanking directly into the expression register would be "against the Vim way"? Is it because of a technical limitation? Is there another reason?

---

**EDIT**

According to the comments, the states of the expression register has changed recently:

My `:version` says:

[image]

And `:h @=`:

[image]

But @romainl and @lcd047 told me that the doc says the register is read-write. So I looked up [the list of the patches](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README) but didn't find one about this change... I have to admit that I'm pretty confused by the situation now.

Comment: I have never used this. What's a typical use for `"=`?

Comment: According to the amazing [practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) it is used to do back-of-the-envelope calculations. What you put into this register is evaluated as a vimscript expression, so you can make simple arithmetic calculations for example. Here I was using it in a file containing several numbers to add and multiply so I was creating a macro to fill my file automatically with the results.

Comment: if you copy that line into register a (without the newline), you can use `:echo eval(@0)` to just find out the result

Comment: @muru The main use is to apply functions in replacements, f.i. I'm doing something like this to shift page numbers in TOCs: `:%s/\v\d+$/\=submatch(0)+9/`.  But it's also quite useful in other contexts, see Drew Neil's [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/simple-calculations-with-vims-expression-register/) on it.

Comment: @statox `:h @=` from my Vim 7.4.1905 says "The expression register is
read-write."

Comment: @lcd047 huh. I never realised that `\=` indicated a register. I always thought it was just Vim's way of doing what `/e` does in Perl.

Comment: @lcd047: Then a patch must have changed this because on my version (`:version` says `rustines incluses: 1-1424, 1426-1558`) just like in the doc I linked it says "read-only". I've searched [here](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README) for a log of this change but couldn't find it.

Comment: @statox Hmm, it changed in an [update](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/2b8388bd0175835eb751e6c58cd0b0b69465f0d9#diff-6f4e6b28f96d34117747184976b738dcR1195) to the runtime files, not in a Vim release.  That was in February 2015.  You can see the [latest version](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/change.txt) of the file at GitHub, but the relevant section doesn't appear to have changed since the commit I mentioned.

Comment: @muru I suppose you can look at it like that too, but Perl's `/e` can run essentially any command, while Vim's `\=` is limited to expressions.  It's actually the `=` register under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The expression register expects an *expression*. `yf4` is not an expression so there's no reason to expect the expression register to make any sense of it.

If you want to use what you just yanked *as an expression*, use `@"`.

Comment: Well `yf4` was just an example. In my case I just mean that a line in my buffer is an expression which can be accepted by the expression register. I think it is reasonable to imagine that a buffer may contain an expression to be processed.

Comment: If you want to use the content of register `a` with the expression register, do `=@a<CR><CR>`. Use `@"`  for the unnamed register. If you want to use the text on the current line, do `=getline('.')<CR><CR>`.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to put some text in the `=` register without using `<c-r>register` but my question was about why the creators of Vim made it read only and not about the different ways to set its content. Still thank you for taking time to write an answer.

Comment: The expression register is *not* "read-only". It's "read-write": you "write" an expression in that register and you "read" the output of that expression. The only difference with more regular registers like `"a` or `"/` is that what you read from `"=` is usually different from what you write into it.